# jquery + handsontable: has no method 'on'

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I'm getting this error:

```
uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

at jquery.handsontable.js:2258

I've got something setup that looks like this:

```
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.handsontable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<div id="dataTable" class="dataTable"></div>
<script>
$j("#dataTable").handsontable();
var data = [
        ["", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];
$j("#dataTable").handsontable("loadData", data);
</script>
```

Comment: if you have a new question that you need help on, please use the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handsontable plugin requires jQuery 1.9+ due to the use of `.on` and other methods not available in older versions of jQuery.

<strike>You could create a small script that implements `.on` to use `.bind` and `.delegate` where appropriate.</strike>

Comment: thanks i was unaware of this and handsontable didn't mention anything about it. I'll make this the answer as soon as I can!

Comment: I'm getting different errors now =( see edits

Comment: Make sure your path to jQuery.js is correct, your code looks good.

Comment: I figured out out. see my answer below if you are curious

Comment: Currently HOT plugin require jQuery 1.9+ or 2.0+ (may work with 1.7+ too, but there are known issues with IE10 https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/410).

Answer (score 5):

You probably need jQuery 1.7

jQuery 1.5 has no `.on` method.  It was introduced to replace `.live()` and provide a more consistent interface for regular vs delegated event handling.

Note that if you make extensive use of `.attr()` you may need to modify your code to use `.prop()` in some places instead - jQuery 1.6 introduced major changes to the way `.attr()` works.